# Django image tag not displaying photo

Tags: django, image, static, django-views, src

I want to show an image by using a img src tag in a Django template file "index.html":

```
templates/
    index.html
static/ 
    img/
       puzzle.png
```

After adding the images to static I collected static and at the top of the page I included:

`{% load static %}`

And my image tag is:

`<img src="{% static 'img/puzzle.png' %}">`

but the image is not showing up on my page. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your `STATIC_ROOT` set in settings.py?

Comment: Double check the values of `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` values.

Comment: @guillermochamorro The STATIC_ROOT is set in settings.py. I know static is working because my CSS is defined in static and the CSS is loading.

Comment: @Saurabh The STATIC values are correct. I know static is working because my CSS is defined in static and the CSS is loading.

Comment: Check the 4th point, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: Can you check what url is rendered in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your directory structure as below,

```
yourapp/
├── templates/
│   └── index.html
└── static/
    └── yourapp
        └── puzzle.png
```

and then in the template,

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'yourapp/puzzle.png' %}">
```

**Reference**
[Configuring static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)